# How can i know which parameter is causing the FormatException ("Input string was not in a correct format") on an OracleCommand Insert?

Tags: c#, database, oracle, formatexception

I have a problem in which I have a huge insert with tons of parameters.

I am using the OracleCommand object to add my parameters prior on executing the query.

Later I execute **ExecuteNonQuery()** method and it gives the FormatException ("Input string was not in a correct format").

**My question is, is there a way I can know which parameter is causing the Exception?**

My code looks something like this

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(_connString))

{

      conn.open();

      using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())

      {
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

          cmd.CommandText = insert (..., ... ,...) into ..... values (nameOfParameter, ..., .... ,...);

          cmd.Parameters.Clear();


          cmd.Parameters.Add("nameOfParameter", OracleDBType.SomeTypeOfData, valueOfParameter, ParameterDirection.Input)

          //Lots of Parameter Adding

          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check every single parameter you are passing to your method.

```
if (parameter1 == null)
    logger.debug("parameter1 is null");
if (parameter2 == null)
    logger.debug("parameter2 is null");
// ...
// You may do something else rather than only logging.
```

Comment: @EnzoDeFilippis, it is not about logging, it is about checking every single parameter.

Comment: But is ther a way, for knowing exactly what is causing the exception, rather than checking every parameter 

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose your code in a

```
try { 
     // entire db transaction code goes here
} catch(Exception e) {
    // you can log the exception and (cross finger) will give you more details 
}
```

Comment: Will the exception details show which parameter threw the exception? I cannot imagine that